# Incompatible library version with Ruby 2.5.8 and Rails 5.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an installed Ruby on Rails app running in production and on my local dev machine. I recently spun up a new beta server in order to upgrade my OS. However, when I completed the setup of the server and started it up, I got the following error from Passenger.

```
incompatible library version - /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so (LoadError)
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:44:in `rescue in with_gems'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/releases/20201220204711/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/releases/20201220204711/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/releases/20201220204711/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/releases/20201220204711/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/releases/20201220204711/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/releases/20201220204711/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `instance_eval'
  /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:382:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

I have tried

- uninstalling msgpack gem and reinstalling
- running gem pristine --all
- bundle install --redownload

and nothing makes any difference whatsoever. I am about to lose my mind. As far as I have been able to see, the setup on my dev, beta, and production machines are identical as is the code being run. However, since I only get an error on the beta server, that cannot possibly be true.

Does anyone see something that I am missing? Any help at all, even simply pointing me in a direction would be most welcome. I simply don't have any more threads to pull on and am at the end of my rope. Help!

---

As requested in the first comment, here are the results of running ldd at the command line. I am running Linux.

```
~$ ldd /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeaa5b8000)
libruby.so.2.5 => /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/libruby.so.2.5 (0x00007fd84b412000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd84b021000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd84ae02000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd84abfe000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fd84a9c6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd84a628000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd84bb57000)
```

---

Here are the location and contents of my gems directory:

```
deploy@estimator-cloud-beta:~$ cd /home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/
deploy@estimator-cloud-beta:~/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems$ ls
actioncable-5.2.4            ffi-1.13.1               rails-dom-testing-2.0.3
actionmailer-5.2.4           globalid-0.4.2           rails-html-sanitizer-1.3.0
actionpack-5.2.4             htmlentities-4.3.4       railties-5.2.4
actionview-5.2.4             i18n-1.8.5               rake-13.0.1
activejob-5.2.4              jbuilder-2.10.1          rb-fsevent-0.10.4
activemodel-5.2.4            jquery-rails-4.4.0       rb-inotify-0.10.1
activerecord-5.2.4           jquery-turbolinks-2.1.0  rdoc-4.3.0
activestorage-5.2.4          json-1.8.6               record_tag_helper-1.0.1
activesupport-5.2.4          less-2.6.0               rubyzip-1.1.7
acts_as_xlsx-1.0.6           less-rails-5.0.0         sass-3.7.4
arel-9.0.0                   loofah-2.7.0             sass-listen-4.0.0
axlsx-2.1.0.pre              mail-2.7.1               sass-rails-5.1.0
axlsx_rails-0.5.2            marcel-0.3.3             sdoc-0.4.2
axlsx_styler-0.2.0           method_source-1.0.0      sprockets-3.7.2
barby-0.6.8                  mimemagic-0.3.5          sprockets-rails-3.2.2
bcrypt-3.1.16                mini_mime-1.0.2          thor-1.0.1
bootsnap-1.4.8               mini_portile2-2.4.0      thread_safe-0.3.6
builder-3.2.4                minitest-5.14.2          tilt-2.0.10
chunky_png-1.3.12            momentjs-rails-2.5.1     turbolinks-5.2.1
coffee-rails-5.0.0           msgpack-1.3.3            turbolinks-source-5.2.0
coffee-script-2.4.1          mysql2-0.5.3             twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.2
coffee-script-source-1.12.2  nio4r-2.5.4              tzinfo-1.2.7
commonjs-0.2.7               nokogiri-1.10.10         uglifier-4.2.0
concurrent-ruby-1.1.7        pagy-3.8.3               websocket-driver-0.7.3
crass-1.0.6                  rack-2.2.3               websocket-extensions-0.1.5
erubi-1.9.0                  rack-test-1.1.0
execjs-2.7.0                 rails-5.2.4
```

---

I spent a few more hours trying to figure out the problem. I used 'gem remove msgpack' to remove the gem. Then I used 'bundle install' and it showed as installed. Then I tried to remove the gem again, and it said it wasn't in the gem file.

After each change above, I also restarted the nginx server to test. The outcome was the same.

I am so frustrated. I am ready to start over, but if there is an error in my configuration, I will got through the whole process and end up with the same problem.

How do I make sure that I completely remove the msgpack gem and then reinstall it from scratch? I'm also open to any other helpful ideas anyone may have on how to proceed. Thanks!

---

As requested, here are the contents my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Export data to spreadsheets
gem 'axlsx', '2.1.0.pre'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'acts_as_xlsx'
gem 'axlsx_styler'
# Barby barcode generator
gem 'barby', '~> 0.6.6'
gem 'bootsnap'
gem 'msgpack'
# gem 'bigdecimal', '>=1.4', '<2.0.0'
gem 'chunky_png'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.2.4'
gem 'railties', '5.2.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4'
# gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 4.2.0'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.5.0'
# gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 3.0.0.1'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 3.2'

# for paginating ActiveRecord search results
gem 'pagy'

# to continue to use div_for which has been deprecated
gem 'record_tag_helper', '~> 1.0'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  # Formtastic - making form creation easier
  gem 'formtastic', '~>3.1.2'

  # Responders for AJAX
  gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.5'
  #gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: "capistrano/rbenv"
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.3'

  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  # gem 'capybara'

  gem 'pry-rails'

end
```

My environments.rb:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Comment: can you look at the library chain of `/home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so` ... on Linux this would be `ldd <file>`, but I believe on MacOS it should be `otool -L <file>`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have added the results of the ldd command at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Where is your gemset? Does your `bundle install` install in `/home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/`, or elsewhere? Is there a chance you have included a file that was compiled on a different platform in your source code?

Comment: Above are the results of ls in that directory. I have the same gems installed on my production server, so I don't think it is a compilation issue. How would I test that?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if you had a different/incompatible version of libc on the 2 different machines, however you might be able to see which is different by `ls -l` on each of the libraries connected to your `ldd` output, on both machines

Comment: @jad Thanks for the suggestion. I don't see anything with the ls -l command. The only thing different is the date when they were installed. The permissions and versions all seem to be the same. Any other (or further) suggestions?

Comment: Only the suggestion of "gem uninstall"ing the msgpack gem again, and trying to run without reinstalling the gem, and see if it deletes the file from the beta directory ...

Comment: @jad I just added an update to the main post. Any more ideas? I am completely stuck.

Comment: Are you using a ruby version manager?

Comment: Yes. I am using rbenv.

Comment: I'm an RVM fan myself ... can you check out https://sadique.io/blog/2013/09/12/managing-gemsets-in-rbenv/ and let me know if you have any of that set up, i.e. the environment variables?

Comment: As far as I know, I am not using gemsets. I didn't do any of those on that website.

Comment: do you know if your `Gemfile` has file paths set in it, are you able to include your Gemfile in the question?

Comment: Contents of Gemfile added to the question.

Comment: nothing untoward :( can you look in your `config/environment.rb` and see if there are lines relating to the `shared/bundle` path?

Comment: Nothing. No occurrence of "bundle" at all in my config/environments.rb. I've posted the contents above.

Comment: do you have your code in a repository that I can access? happy to take this offline to look for a solution

Comment: I do. It in a private github repo. Happy to share but not sure how that would help. I use the same repo to send to beta and prod servers. Only having this issue on the new beta server. Same version of Ubuntu on both servers. Same versions of Ruby and Rails as well.

Comment: I know in rvm, there is an issue with `gem pristine` that it actually advises against, since it doesn't clear objects from the gemset.  it's complete overkill, but can you empty the `/home/deploy/EstimatorHiQ/beta/shared/bundle/` directory and use bundle to reinstall? (or you could move it out of the way, rather than empty it)

Comment: I renamed the one directory under bundle (changed it from "ruby" to "ybur"). Then went to the app directory and ran "bundle install". No change. Still getting the same error. Maybe it is time to just bite the bullet and try a fresh install on a new server instance.

Comment: I think you're right. Sorry I couldn't help more

Comment: @jad Thanks for all your time and assistance. I sincerely appreciate it. Not sure what I did differently, but I was able to start over and successfully deploy my new BETA server now!